# How to get value after using str_replace once?

Tags: php

I have using str_replace function to separate specific value after that I want to get again value on it.

Example:

```
function getPID($conf,$fdata){
global $text;
$pid = $fdata[offer];
$pid = str_replace(array('p='),"\t",$pid);
$pid = str_replace(array('&sid'),"\t",$pid);
$pid = str_replace(array(" "),"\n",$pid);
return $pid;
}
```

I use this str_replace to separate

> k=Apple+iPhone+5c+32GB&m=Digital+Rev&p=567d02921b38c979f8cd43c7109bc177&sid=%23%23permalink%23%23&referrer=

A result after using str_replace and call pid will is following:

> Apple+iPhone+5c+32GB&m=Digital+Rev&
>   567d02921b38c979f8cd43c7109bc177
>   =%23%23permalink%23%23&referrer=

However, I want to get value as **567d02921b38c979f8cd43c7109bc177** only not include above line and bottom line.

How can I get it? Is it possible to get this value?

Comment: just simple unserialize and get the value of p

Comment: @E2B: I don't think `unserialize()` would help. It's a [query string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19874996/1438393) :)

Comment: Yes, you're right, i've to look twice..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a query string, so you can simply use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str) to parse it:

```
$str = '...';
parse_str($str, $params);
echo $params['p']; // => 567d02921b38c979f8cd43c7109bc177
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/64524)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

However, a value not specific only 567d02921b38c979f8cd43c7109bc177 because $fdata[offer]; is function which include a data in multiple lines.

I try to test with your code as:

function getPID($conf,$fdata){

 global $text;
 $str = $fdata[offer];

 parse_str($str, $params);

 echo $params['p'];
}

and call pid value in html template and it give empty value.

Comment: @user2971638: You aren't returning the output. Change your function to [this](https://eval.in/64641).

Comment: I using your function in php file now. However, after I called ##pid## it was nothing to display as empty value ;(

Comment: @user2971638: Sorry, I don't understand your question?

Comment: Should I put any function before $pid = getPID(REPLACE_THIS, REPLACE_THIS);? I declare ##pid## to called $pid value but when I put it on file. It wasn't display a value of $pid. Or Should I put any value in REPLACE_THIS?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you're trying to solve a different problem.

Comment: Did you mean a new thread? Or how can I sent example file to show you?

Thank

Comment: No, I mean a new question. Click on the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) link and ask your question -- make sure you include all the relevant details.

Comment: Thank, I will ask a new question in few minutes.

Comment: I ask as new question now. Please help me to review too.

Thank

Comment: I can get a value now. Thank you for your helped :)